# How can I filter multiple factor levels by multiple dates in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have multiple grouping variables (id) and I want to filter each one with its own specific date.

```
mydata <- structure(list(ID = structure(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C")), 
    Start = structure(c(1357038060, 1357221074, 1357369644, 1357834170, 
    1357913412, 1358151763, 1358691675, 1358789411, 1359538400
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), End = structure(c(1357110430, 
    1357365312, 1357564413, 1358230679, 1357978810, 1358674600, 
    1358853933, 1359531923, 1359568151), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("Line", "Start", "End"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

I could do it individually with the following but how do I tie this together into one line?

```
mydata %>% filter(id == "A" & time >= as.Date("2013-01-01 00:00:00")) 
mydata %>% filter(id == "B" & time >= as.Date("2013-01-13 00:00:00")) 
mydata %>% filter(id == "C" & time >= as.Date("2013-01-23 00:00:00"))
```

Comment: Just separate them by `|` in a single statement? e.g. `(id == "A" & time >= as.Date("2013-01-01 00:00:00")) | (id == "B" & time >= as.Date("2013-01-13 00:00:00"))  | (id == "C" & time >= as.Date("2013-01-23 00:00:00"))`

Answer (score 2):

If there are many dates, then can use a loop

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
v1 <- unique(mydata$Line)
dates <- as.POSIXct(c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-13", "2013-01-23"))
mydata %>% 
    filter(map2(v1, dates, ~ Line== .x & Start >= .y) %>%
             reduce(`|`))
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are many dates, I suggest to use a *non-equi join* either using SQL (package `sqldf`) or `data.table`

For this, a table with filter conditions is created, e.g.,

```
fc <- data.frame(Line = LETTERS[1:3],
                 dates = as.POSIXct(c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-13", "2013-01-23")))
fc
```

> ```
>   Line      dates
> 1    A 2013-01-01
> 2    B 2013-01-13
> 3    C 2013-01-23
> ```

(Note that `dates` is of type `POSIXct` to be in line with `Start` and `End`)

#### sqldf

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select mydata.* from mydata join fc on mydata.Line = fc.Line and mydata.Start >= fc.dates")
```

> ```
>   Line               Start                 End
> 1    A 2013-01-01 12:01:00 2013-01-02 08:07:10
> 2    A 2013-01-03 14:51:14 2013-01-05 06:55:12
> 3    A 2013-01-05 08:07:24 2013-01-07 14:13:33
> 4    B 2013-01-14 09:22:43 2013-01-20 10:36:40
> 5    C 2013-01-30 10:33:20 2013-01-30 18:49:11
> ```

BTW,

```
sqldf("select mydata.* from mydata, fc where mydata.Line = fc.Line and mydata.Start >= fc.dates")
```

returns the same result.

#### data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[mydata[fc, on = .(Line, Start >= dates ), which = TRUE]]
```

> ```
>    Line               Start                 End
> 1:    A 2013-01-01 12:01:00 2013-01-02 08:07:10
> 2:    A 2013-01-03 14:51:14 2013-01-05 06:55:12
> 3:    A 2013-01-05 08:07:24 2013-01-07 14:13:33
> 4:    B 2013-01-14 09:22:43 2013-01-20 10:36:40
> 5:    C 2013-01-30 10:33:20 2013-01-30 18:49:11
> ```

The expression

```
mydata[fc, on = .(Line, Start >= dates ), which = TRUE]
```

returns the indices of the rows of `mydata` which fulfill the conditions

> ```
> [1] 1 2 3 6 9
> ```